# Read data from protected object in PHP

Tags: php, object, protected

I have this chunk of code in PHP (it just retrieve some delivery methotds from API, API is 3rd party)

```
use MPAPI\Services\DeliveryMethods;
use MPAPI\Services\Deliveries;
use MPAPI\Entity\PartnerDelivery;
use MPAPI\Entity\GeneralDelivery;
$deliveryMethods = new DeliveryMethods($mpapiClient);
$response = $deliveryMethods->get();
var_dump($response);
```

And response is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(MPAPI\Entity\DeliveryMethod)#35 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(7) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(4) "Test"
      ["title"]=>
      string(18) "Testovacia doprava"
      ["price"]=>
      int(10)
      ["cod_price"]=>
      int(10)
      ["free_limit"]=>
      int(0)
      ["delivery_delay"]=>
      int(5)
      ["is_pickup_point"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  object(MPAPI\Entity\DeliveryMethod)#36 (1) {
    ["data":protected]=>
    array(7) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(3) "UPS"
      ["title"]=>
      string(22) "Kuriérska služba UPS"
      ["price"]=>
      int(5)
      ["cod_price"]=>
      int(0)
      ["free_limit"]=>
      int(0)
      ["delivery_delay"]=>
      int(4)
      ["is_pickup_point"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to access it in PHP, so my foreach loop looks like:

```
<?php foreach ($response[0]->data as $item) { ?>
// ...
<?php } ?>
```

But I get an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property
>   MPAPI\Entity\DeliveryMethod::$data in
>   /data/web/virtuals/175241/virtual/www/doprava.php:39 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in /data/web/virtuals/175241/virtual/www/doprava.php on
>   line 39

So how to correctly read this data in PHP?

**If I change foreach loop like this:**

```
<?php foreach ($response as $item) { ?>
// ...
<?php } ?>
```

I will get another error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type
>   MPAPI\Entity\DeliveryMethod as array

At API's documentation there is nothing about that https://github.com/mallgroup/mpapi-client-php/blob/master/doc/DELIVERIES.md

Comment: Have you looked at the API's documentation, there probably are Getters for these private properties.

Comment: I looked at API's documentation, but there is nothing https://github.com/mallgroup/mpapi-client-php/blob/master/doc/DELIVERIES.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you, the documentation is not too clear about that. 
If you look at [the source](https://github.com/mallgroup/mpapi-client-php/blob/06f4dae9b3b5b398d68374db36e4f16ab7fc266d/src/Entity/DeliveryMethod.php), you can see that the class `MPAPI\Entity\DeliveryMethod` has this method which returns the data as an array :

```
/**
 * @see \MPAPI\Entity\AbstractEntity::getData()
 */
public function getData()
{
    return [
        self::KEY_ID => $this->getId(),
        self::KEY_TITLE => $this->getTitle(),
        self::KEY_PRICE => $this->getPrice(),
        self::KEY_COD_PRICE => $this->getCodPrice(),
        self::KEY_FREE_LIMIT => $this->getFreeLimit(),
        self::KEY_DELIVERY_DELAY => $this->getDeliveryDelay(),
        self::KEY_PICKUP_POINT => $this->isPickupPoint()
    ];
}
```

So, you would do something like this

```
<?php 
$methodList = $deliveryMethods->get();
foreach ($methodList as $method) { 
    $methodData = $method->getData();
    // OR
    $methodTitle = $method->getTitle()
    // ...
} 
?>
```

Comment: Yes I know that it will return an array, I dumped it (it is in my question), but I don't know how to correctly access these values, everytime I got an error. I would like to do "foreach ($response as $item)" but it throws an error.